# Initialize a Bluetooth connection in an activity and use the connected bluetooth device in a service

Tags: android, service, bluetooth, arduino

I want to select and connect to a Bluetooth device (Serial communication) in an activity and use the same Connection in an Service. The Service works in Background and do some calculations and send a string with the Bluetooth Connection to a arduino device every time my Location is changed.

The Service runs as long as I desroy it.

I only want to know how can I use the same Connection from my activity in my Service.